# Design of website pushing info to the app, or app retrieving from website

Tags: android

I have a design question about Android app and I am not sure if I can ask it here (If not please advise when I can ask).

I want to make an app where it gets information from a website (or actually make the website push locations to the app). Imagine a webform that has 3 fields (3 trucks locations). I want that everytime  I put those values and click submit, The android app on the devices will show the location of the trucks on the map. I am familiar with the google maps so I know how to show 3 dots on the map given the location. I also know how to write HTML code that would do POST/GET upon press of a submit button But the communication and how to initiate this trigger on the app is what I am confused about.  So it is more of an architecture design question. I need a starting point to know where to start looking. I hope I delivered my point here.

sooo Any help ?:)

Comment: Search terms: websockets (latest versions of HTML5 browsers), long poll (all browsers), or just JavaScript `setInterval` to do basic polling.

Comment: But I want them to be sent to the app. How does the app know that there is new data available?!

Comment: "HTML code that would do POST/GET ..." confused me... Depending on language you are using it should be easy to call a REST method on a web site on timer as easiest polling solution. Push generally a bit harder and using existing libraries for both sides would be advisable.

Comment: Ohhh I see so I should have timer in android app that will keep polling website for new Data rather than pushing data from website upon "submit". Is this what you mean? If so, then the submit will have to store info somewhere  so I can pull it by a  timer. No?

Comment: Yes. Storing somewhere (memory/file) is needed for polling.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your talking about setting up push notifications, look at http://parse.com/products/push

Comment: Hmm interesting. But i there a way not involving 3rd party product

Comment: setting up your own push notifications server would be difficult and costly, but like above if you wrote your own api and then had the application poll the api through a service every so often, or had the user check for it would be your best bet

Comment: Ok I see similar to what Alexei said in the comment above. So I guess the pushing is out of question for me. The question that remains, if I poll data, what am I polling? A text file that is being saved on the server upon clicking submit?

Comment: I guess you could save the form data to a database and then poll that database when the service updates and then parse that data into a google map on the phone

Comment: Perfect! thats what I was looking for. Last question, Can I pull data from db directly from my app, or should I have an api like PHP script in the middle or some sort of other thing?

Answer (score 3):

This may be a use case for using [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). I have not worked with GCM yet but this is one option.

Another idea is to setup an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to schedule the fetching for data. One draw back I can think of is if you set the AlarmManager to be frequent (ex: every 10 minutes) then all those network requests are going to drain the battery quickly.

Another alternative and similar to the polling, is to have a button within the application where the user manually presses to get the latest data.

Comment: +1 for the new GCM answer and suggestion. I was looking for more the other components involved outside the app